# iPhone/iPad - Problem with Copy values of NSArray into NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisearchbar

This code is the search code

```
- (void) searchTableView {
 NSLog(@"4");
 NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
 NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems)
 {
  NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];
  [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
 }

 for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
 {
  NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

  if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
   [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
 }
 //NSLog(@"Count - %d",[copyListOfItems count]);
 [searchArray release];
 searchArray = nil;
}
```

I want to implement this type of search in my array but i am getting error in below line.

```
[searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
```

when control comes on this line application shutdown every time can any one help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line will give you an error only if array has nothing in it(nil value).

So check what is the value of array using nslog.

Comment: Thanks sir now it's working!!! Your the one who give me the idea to implement this....thanks a lot.